# If you have a field isomorphism and the domain is algebraically closed then so is the image?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I know it makes sense because if they are isomorphic they are practically the same thing, but what would a proof look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your field isomorphism is $f: K \to L$. Take a non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $L$, apply $f^{-1}$ to get a non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $K$. This has a root, since $K$ is algebraically closed; call it $x$. Then you can easily check that $f(x)$ is a root of your original polynomial.

Comment: Most straight forward proof one can ask for. Thanks :)

Comment: Does that mean all embeddings of algebraic closures are isomorphic?

Comment: @user121615 What do you mean by that? Embeddings into what?

Comment: A map from two algebraic closures of F. The embedding between the two. That must be isomorphic too, right?